# Recreating stage layout in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, instance, movieclip, stage

I have 27 MovieClips in my Library which are all images.  At the moment they are positioned on the stage as instances of their parent and then made to function in the first frame of my actions layer.  I want to recreate this layout solely in code so there is nothing on the stage.  How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on a movieclip in the library, then go to Properties.
Tick "Export for ActionScript", then check the name where it says "Class". Hit OK.
Let's say this name was "Symbol1".

Then type this script:

```
var symbol1:MovieClip = new Symbol1();
addChild(symbol1);
```

var symbol1 means you created a variable, MovieClip is the type. This MovieClip variable is a "new " Symbol1 (this was the name in the library, Properties, Class.

Then add this to the stage:

```
addChild(symbol1)
```

If you want to position it on the stage, set the coordinates of the variable:

```
symbol1.x = 10;
symbol1.y = 10;
```

puts it to (10, 10).

Depending on how many objects you have you can type this code for each one of them (don't forget to Export them for actionscript in Library->Properties).

If you have tons of movieclips and you don't want to type evertyhing, but would rather write some dynamic code, give us a hint on your library structure and how you named your objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help anemgyenge.  I followed your instructions exactly (I think).  My library MovieClips are called "one", "two", "three", "four" and so on. I now get the error 1180 Call to a possibly undefined method one.

Comment: I also get error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: one.

Comment: In the library, where you see your MovieClips, right click on the elements, then go to Property and choose "Export for ActionScript". Did you find this part?

Comment: Also don't use "one" for variable name. So don't write var one:MovieClip = new one(), but something like var one1:MovieClip = new one(). It's important, that these elements should be MovieClips. Did this solve it?

Comment: Thank you very much.  That has probably saved me hours!  Cheers :)

Comment: Your welcome :) (if you accept this as an answer to your question, you can click on the tick mark next to my answer.)